# VB convert MM:SS timecode to seconds

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use time span  and total seconds but it can't convert string to long. This is the code I have so far, I am trying to convert a `timestamp` in the format of HH:MM:SS and MM:SS (stored in a `listbox`) to total seconds then set the play head / current position (of window media player) to the total seconds of the time stamp. the error i am getting is Conversion from string  to type 'Long' is not valid.

```
Stamp = "01:22:22" 

Dim SetPos As New TimeSpan(Stamp)'error happens just here (Conversion from string  to type 'Long' is not valid.)
Dim Seconds As Double = SetPos.TotalSeconds


Dim controls As WMPLib.IWMPControls3 = plrVideo.Ctlcontrols
controls.currentPosition = Seconds 'setting play head to seconds from start
```

Sorry for the terrible code I've only been coding for a little bit.

Comment: Using TimeSpan.TryParse() would be an obvious approach, it is unclear why you are not using it.

Comment: I changed the question to make more sence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its way over complicated but this is what i ended up with thanks to D le

```
Dim timeString = Stamp.Split(":")

    If UBound(timeString) = 2 Then

        Dim hour = timeString(0)
        Dim min = timeString(1)
        Dim sec = timeString(2)

        Dim totalSecs As Integer = CInt(hour) * 60 * 60 + CInt(min) * 60 + CInt(sec)

        SetPos = totalSecs
    Else
        If UBound(timeString) = 1 Then
            Dim min = timeString(0)
            Dim sec = timeString(1)

            Dim totalSecs As Integer = CInt(min) * 60 + CInt(sec)

            SetPos = totalSecs
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Did you even *try* the suggested `Timespan.TryParse()`?

Comment: i played around with it but i could not figure it out sorry

Comment: *Playing around* and guessing how things work is a highly inefficient way to write bad code

Comment: You didn't give me any info on what it does or how it works and i could not find much online

Comment: You need to get your Google-Fu on: [TimeSpan.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e.aspx) also available via F1

Answer (score 1):

Following function will return the number of seconds from your strings:

```
Function GetSeconds(Stamp As String) As Long
    Try
        'Try the format "hh:mm:ss", when failed then try "mm:ss"
        Return TimeSpan.ParseExact(Stamp, {"hh\:mm\:ss", "mm\:ss"}, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TotalSeconds
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Invalid Format!
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function
```

Output examples:

```
Debug.WriteLine(GetSeconds("30:03"))       '--> 1803
Debug.WriteLine(GetSeconds("01:22:22"))    '--> 4942
Debug.WriteLine(GetSeconds("01:23:45:67")) '--> -1 (Error)
```

Comment: Half the time my time stamps are only in the format MM:SS so this would only work for HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get a 'HH:MM:SS'-like string in

```
lblDebug.Text = Stamp
```

If my guess is correct, you could do a

```
Dim timeString = lblDebug.Text.Split(":")
Dim hour = timeString(0)
Dim min = timeString(1)
Dim sec = timeString(2)
Dim totalSecs as Integer = CInt(hour)*60*60 + CInt(min)*60 + CInt(sec)
msg(totalSecs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I got this in return "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'" for sec

Comment: can you set a breakpoint in the line 'lblDebug.Text = Stamp ' and tell us the content of that variable?

Comment: After your edit it breaks again (but in a different way) because it's trying to convert the 'HH' string into an integer... give Stamp a logical value (eg "01:23:45")

Comment: it is a string saying "30:03" and btw i changed the question a bit

Comment: I saw ;) 30:03 its not a valid "time string" unless those are 30 min and 3 seconds

Comment: yeh i am an idiot i just realised that its looking for 3 separation and that would be two. How would i stop that

Answer (score 0):

When you want to parse a time string in the format "[[HH:]MM:]SS" you can use the following short snippet:

```
Function ParseTime( timeAsString As String) As TimeSpan 

    Dim secondsAsLong As Long
    For Each partAsString In timeAsString.Split(":")

        Dim partAsLong As Long
        Long.TryParse(partAsString, partAsLong)

        secondsAsLong *= 60
        secondsAsLong += partAsLong
    Next

    Dim timeAsTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsAsLong)

    Return timeAsTimeSpan
End Function
```

That gives you the possibility to parse all variants of time strings, as long as they are either

- only seconds ("30")
- minutes and seconds ("30:03")
- or complete hours, minutes and seconds ("1:22:22")

Also an empty input will result in a valid `TimeSpan` with the value zero.

In fact all invalid parts between the `:` will be handled as beeing `0`

Comment: it just returned 0 i dont have much time to look into it atm  so i will update soon